# IOS - scheduleLocalNotification on production

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm using scheduleLocalNotification for UILocalNotification from AppDelefate and everything goes well on debug provision.
But when i test my app on Ad Hoc provision - it does not fire the notification.
Can anybody guide me on that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - local notification does not depend on profiles. You miss it with PushNotifications.

Are you sure that you schedule notification? Maybe you forgot to request user permission?

This is how it should looks like:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories: nil))
  let notification = UILocalNotification()
  notification.alertBody = "body"
  notification.alertAction = "open"
  notification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60)
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
  notification.userInfo = ["myKey": "myValue"]
  notification.category = "category"
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
} else {
  // do nothing
  // iOS 7 and prior does not require permission
}
```